# How can I return contents of ListView with OnItemClickListener (Getting ljava.lang.string;@ instead)

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make it so when I click on an item in my **ListView** I will have it return what is inside. **For example,** the first row reads **"Julie / Lireal / Paladin"**, and when I click on it, I'd like that returned (or just Julie, or just Lieral, etc.)

They are added from **single_list_item.xml** in three separate **lists column_one - column_three**.

MAINACTIVITY.JAVA
    package com.example.tediousb.readcsv;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private ListView listView;
private ItemArrayAdapter itemArrayAdapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    //On Create Starts Here
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list_view);
    itemArrayAdapter = new ItemArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),             R.layout.single_list_item);
    Parcelable state = listView.onSaveInstanceState();
    listView.setAdapter(itemArrayAdapter);
    listView.onRestoreInstanceState(state);

    InputStream inputStream =     getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mystatsfile);
    CSVReader csv = new CSVReader(inputStream);
    List<String[]> scoreList = csv.read();

    for(String[] scoreData:scoreList){
        itemArrayAdapter.add(scoreData);
        Log.d("send to IAA:", scoreData[1]);
    }







    final ListView work_with_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list_view);

    work_with_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {



            //kinda working:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+" / You've pressed an item ID: "+ work_with_list.getItemIdAtPosition(position)+" / ENTRY:"+work_with_list.getItemAtPosition(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}

public void showToastMessage(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You've pressed the e-mail button",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}



}
```

ItemArrayAdapter

```
public class ItemArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String[]> {


private List<String[]> scoreList = new ArrayList<String[]>();

static class ItemViewHolder{
    TextView player_name;
    TextView character_name;
    TextView character_class;

}

public ItemArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}


public void add(String[] object){
    scoreList.add(object);
    super.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.scoreList.size();
}

@Override
public String[] getItem(int position){
    return this.scoreList.get(position);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ItemViewHolder viewHolder;

    if(row==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_list_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder();
        viewHolder.player_name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.column_one);
        viewHolder.character_name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.column_two);
        viewHolder.character_class = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.column_three);
        row.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }


    String[] stat = getItem(position);
    Log.d("ItemArray",stat[0] + "/" + stat[1] +"/"+ stat[2]);
    viewHolder.player_name.setText(stat[0]);
    viewHolder.character_name.setText(stat[1]);
    viewHolder.character_class.setText(stat[2]);
    return row;


}
}
```

The toast, however, returns not what's in the list view but rather         **"Ljava.lang.String;@#####".**

CSVReader

```
public class CSVReader {
InputStream inputStream;

public CSVReader(InputStream is){
    this.inputStream = is;
}

public List<String[]> read(){
    List<String[]> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    try{
        String csvLine;
        while((csvLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
            String[] row = csvLine.split(",");
            resultList.add(row);
            Log.d("Reading File in CSVReader", csvLine);
        }

    }catch(IOException ex){
        throw new RuntimeException("Error in Reading CSV file:" + ex);
    }finally{
        try{
            inputStream.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Error while Closing input stream:"+e);
        }
    }
    return resultList;

}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
    android:onClick="showToastMessage"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.tediousb.readcsv.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_list_view"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top">
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

single_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/column_one"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/single_item_margin"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/column_two"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/single_item_margin"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:id="@+id/column_three"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/column_width_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/single_item_margin"/>

<!--<TextView-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:text="New Text"-->
    <!--android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/textView"-->
    <!--android:layout_alignParentTop="true"-->
    <!--android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"-->
    <!--android:layout_marginTop="447dp" />-->


</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried to add more of the code, but it doesn't format properly.  I am new to this board, and would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: What is the item of your listview. If its an object instead of a string you will only get the name of the object instead of the data.  Show the data you send to the listView

Comment: I've added all the code.  When I use "work_with_list.getItemAtPosition(position)" it returns the Ljava stuff with a different hex number of 7 characters after the @.  For example, clicking on the first item (which returns an ID of 0 with getItemIDAtPosition) returns [LJava.lang.String;@2572156  The second (ID1) returns LJava.lang.String;@ed2b1ea

Answer (score 0):

You toast the id if this view

```
listview.getItemAtPosition(position)
```

instead extract your layout,textview or sth from this view and make a toast, you'll get your answer

**UPDATE**
This might be what you wanted

```
RelativeLayout item = (RelativeLayout)(listview.getItemAtPosition(position));
TextView col1 = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.column_one);
TextView col2 = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.column_two);
TextView col3 = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.column_three);
String first = col1.getTetxt();
String second = col2.getText();
String third = col3.getText();
```

Comment: That's in the code.  That's actually what's returning the LJAVA... information.

Answer (score 0):

You are manipulating arrays of Strings in your adapter, so this is what you get when you call `work_with_list.getItemAtPosition(position)`

To display the name you need to access the "cell" in the array where the name is stored, so that would be `work_with_list.getItemAtPosition(position)[0]` (careful with NPE or ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException here).

A better approach is to manipulate a model class in your adapter, for example:

- create a class `Stat` that contains 3 public String properties `playerName, characterName and characterClass`
- change your CSV reader method to create a Stat object for each line read, add it to the list and and return the `List<Stat>`
- change your adapter to manipulate `Stat` objects instead of `String[]`
- change `work_with_list.getItemAtPosition(position)[0]` into `work_with_list.getItemAtPosition(position).playerName` to display the player's name in the toast when you press an item in the list